# JS Google Drive SDK

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

Hi I am looking to create an application that creates a spreadsheet on the behalf of a user and edits the spreadsheet using javascript. Is this possible or would I have to use a different language. I noticed ZOHO sheet has done this. I just don't know what language they are using. I noticed that not all functionalities are javascript support. Please let me know on the links for where to get started on this with javascript. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a separate app that edits the spreadsheet externally, you can use Javascript in conjunction with the Spreadsheet API at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

Alternatively you can embed Javascript within your spreadsheet using Apps Script as described here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/

It really depends what you are trying to achieve.